# Fade slide animation when using intent for bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation, transition

I have a navigation bar at the bottom with icons. When I click on an icon a new activity starts with intent.

```
context.startActivity(intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
```

Like this.
If I test it on my Android Pixel emulator the animation is always from bottom to top when a new activity starts. 
If I test it on my physical android device (Android 7.1) the animation is always from right to left when a new activity starts. When I close an activity the animation goes from left to right away.

I want always this slide animation (like on my physical device). What do I have to do?

I added

```
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

In the onCreate() of the activites, so I have the slide when the activity starts, but no slide animation when the activity close.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need 2 new animation files in your anim folder and some code in the Activity which you want to close with the animation, add changes to `onBackPressed` method

First the animation files: **left_to_right.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**right_to_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

And in **Activity** do the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
}
```

PS Also be aware that even if your code is okay, your phone might have animation turned off

Comment: Thanks for the two xml files, these are working. onBackPressed is working, when I use the back button of the device. But it don't work when I navigate with the navigation bar. I tried it also with onResume but it's called always thus the activity comes always from the left. With onRestart it works better... but thank you

Comment: Don't try it with onResume! Try it with onPause() it should help with your nav bar problem! If my code solved your issue , mark the answer as accepted to close this thread